# Whats maximum and minimum of $4x + y^2$ without Lagrange

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Whats maximum and minimum of $4x + y^2$ without Lagrange
>
> constraints = $2x^2 + y^2 =4$

Substitute $y^2= 4-2x^2$ into $4x+y^2$ we get $4x+4-2x^2$ manipulate it into $-2(x-1)^2 + 6$ the maximum is 6. Or using differentiation we get $x=1$ and only produces maximum value. What about the minimun? Also find the maximum in different way?

Comment: Well, we know $x\in \left[-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2\right]$.

Comment: The final equation represents an inverted parabola which has a minimum of $-\infty$.

Comment: @Sam  But most of that parabola fails to satisfy the constraint.

Comment: In general, the maximum (or minimum) is either at a stationary point *or* at the boundary. This last possibility is often forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=4x+4-2x^2=$

$-2(x-1)^2+6$;

1)$2x^2+y^2=4$;

An ellipse: $x^2/(√2)^2+y^2/2^2=1$.

Semi minor axis : $√2$ ;

$y^2=0: x_{1,2}=\pm √2$;

Minimum:

$x=-√2$: $f_{min}(-√2)=-2(-√2-1)^2 +6=-2(1+√2)^2 +6$.

See also comments.